# How to reference a color variable in a xml resource file

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I have this XML in my res/drawable directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="10dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#706969" />
         <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#117e7a7a" android:endColor="#BB7e7a7a" />            
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

I want to put in `android:startColor="#117e7a7a"` a reference to a variable instead of a color value. ¿How can be that done? I can't find any info about that in google

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml) is explained how resources (such as color) can be referred to from other resources/layouts.

In short, use :

```
android:startColor="@color/myColor" ...
```

where "myColor" could be  defined in values/colors.xml as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="myColor">#117e7a7a</color>
    .... more colors
</resources>
```

Comment: thanks! and how can i apply a mask to that color variable in my xml selector file in my drawables dir? i mean, i want to appli a mask with some more clear color or with some transparency in some cases. How can i apply that masc to "color/myColor" ?

Comment: Are you talking about applying alpha mask ? I don't think it works for colors, rather for paint and have to be don programmatically.

Comment: i'm talking about aplying a mask to the color, for example, if the color is #111111 i want to sum #333333 and the result must be #444444. How can i do that?

Comment: I haven't seen color being a sum of integers, but you can still do it, although you will have to do it programmatically. Anyways, you can post it as a different question it has nothing to do with you originally asked. Here is the code : `int color1 = res.getColor(R.color.myColor);//#11111 int color2 = res.getColor(R.color.mask);//#333333; int colorRes = color1+color2;`

Comment: i must apply it in the xml, i can't do int...etc

Comment: I don't think it can be done. And it is not what you asked for in your question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `colors.xml` file in `res/values`. Inside that document, create your color variables.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="textColorPrimary">#ffffff</color>

</resources>
```

Reference your colors with `@colors/textColorPrimary`

Comment: thanks! and how can i apply a mask to that color variable in my xml selector file in my drawables dir? i mean, i want to appli a mask with some more clear color or with some transparency in some cases. How can i apply that masc to "color/rextColorPrimary" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: i'm talking about aplying a mask to the color, for example, if the color is #111111 i want to sum #333333 and the result must be #444444. How can i do that?